# Select values with latest date for each repeated column value

Tags: mysql

I have a table where a column 'name' has got repetitive values. I want to select values only with the latest Date. The table looks like this:

[image]

I need to write a query to be able to grab the latest id by date

The answer should be:

[image]

I have tried using this query but it dint help,

```
SELECT tt.*
FROM myTable tt
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT ID, MAX(Date) AS MaxDateTime
    FROM myTable
    GROUP BY ID) groupedtt 
ON tt.ID = groupedtt.ID 
AND tt.Date = groupedtt.MaxDateTime
```

Any other solution please?

Thanks,

Comment: That query should work. What's the datatype of the `Date` column?

Comment: If it's `VARCHAR` rather than `DATETIME`, you need to parse it with `STR_TO_DATE()`, since the strings are not in a sortable format.